# Help understanding web services

Tags: web-services

I know what is soap,wsdl and uddi.
But what is the relation between them and how to establish the relationship in code.
It will be good if someone can post a sample code which has all of these.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What platform are you using? Java? .NET? BTW, ignore UDDI. It was a failed experiment.

Answer (score 2):

SOAP is the XML-based protocol used to send and receive web service messages. WSDL is the XML-based language used to describe the format of the messages, and the details of the interaction with the service.

UDDI is not used very much. It sounded like a good idea at the time it was invented, but turned out not to be useful.